# Calculate length of segments on a line in kilometers in R

Tags: r, geospatial, distance

I have a GTFS from a bus network and would like to calculate the distance in kilometers between each pair of stops within a given line.

I have two list of pairs (lon,lat). The first list represents the route and the second one the stops. It's important to notice that the stops can be on the line or next to it, so they can or cannot be part of the first list of points:

```
linea <- shape_ruta %>% 
select(shape_pt_lon, shape_pt_lat)

puntos <- viaje_ruta %>% 
select(stop_lon, stop_lat)
```

[head of linea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Izlzu.png)

[head of puntos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prbz8.png)

What I've done til now is identifying the points of the line that are closest to the stops with the following code:

```
d = dist2Line(puntos, linea, distfun=distHaversine)
plot(makeLine(linea), type = 'l')
points(linea)
points(puntos, col = 'blue', pch = 20)
points(d[,2], d[,3], col = 'red', pch = 'x')
for (i in 1:nrow(d)) lines(gcIntermediate(puntos[i,], d[i,2:3], 10), lwd = 2)
```

With that I get "d" that are the closest point in the line to each stop and the following graph:

[Graph with the line, stops and closest points in the line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQBJM.png)

What I don't know how to do now is to calculate the distance in kilometers of each of this segment (from one red point to the other, that are basically the points in "d") following the shape of the line.

I've been with this for a few days now and some help would be much appreciated :)